# Finding ring endomorphisms.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ring-theory

I need to find $\varphi \in \operatorname{End}(\mathbb{R}[x])$ such that there's a function $\psi \in \operatorname{End}(\mathbb{R}[x]), \psi \neq 0$ such that $\psi \circ \varphi = 0$ but there's no $\Gamma \in \operatorname{End}(\mathbb{R}[x]), \Gamma \neq 0$ such that $\varphi \circ \Gamma=0$.

To be clear, I'm talking about RING endomorphisms.

In other words I'm looking for a ring endomorphism from the reals to the reals which is a right divisor of 0 but not a left divisor of 0.

I've considered a functions such as the derivative, mod x ($\varphi(a_0x^0+...+a_nx^n) = a_0$) but none seem to work, I thought I had it once but the function I defined turned out to not be a homomorphism.

Thanks a million!

Comment: If you want to write *different* use `\neq`.

Comment: Your question is incoherent: The ring $\mathbb R\left[x\right]$ isn't "the reals". But that's not the main problem. The main problem is that ring endomorphisms, in the standard meaning of this word, take $1$ to $1$ and therefore cannot be $0$ unless the ring is the trivial ring. Even if you allow endomorphisms of **nonunital** rings, such $\varphi$ and $\Gamma$ still don't exist. Are you sure you mean RING endomorphisms? I could easily imagine the above problem for $\mathbb R$-vector space endomorphisms being posed as an instructive homework problem on linear algebra.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you got $\phi \in End(\mathbb{R}[x])$ and $\phi \in End(\mathbb{R}[x])$ such that $\psi \neq 0$ and $\psi \circ \phi = 0$.

In other words, $Im(\phi) \subset Ker(\psi)$ and $Ker(\psi)$ is not the whole space. Therefore $Im(\phi)$ is not the whole space ; thus $Ker(\phi)$ is not $\{0\}$.

It is now easy to produce $\Gamma \in End(\mathbb{R}[x])$ such that $Im(\Gamma) \subset Ker(\phi)$ and $\Gamma \neq 0$ (for instance the projection into $Ker(\phi)$ will do).

Thus $\phi \circ \Gamma = 0$.

Therefore the is no endomorphism $\phi$ that fits your criteria!

Comment: Can someone verify this? This wasn't a prove/disprove exercise, I'd be surprised if they had me look for something that doesn't exist.

Comment: Koen gave all the details, Joc: you can check his answer yourself1